# what exactly is sent from the resource server to the authentication server In spring security oauth2 during token validation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I understand that a resource server will make a call to the authentication server with a token to confirm that it is valid. 
However is this token the same Cookie: JSESSIONID?

Comment: It sends token as you mentioned,also sends authentication header. JSESSIONID has nothing to do with sending request to check token endpoint.Client receives token from authorization server where this token was generated( JSESSIONID not involved)and then stored in appropriate token store and then client uses this token to make an api call to resource server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oauth 2.0 Bearer tokens are of two types - General tokens(e.g like java uuid string) and JWT tokens.
General tokens will be stored in the authorization server token store along with their scopes, expiry, client ID, UserId and other related information. When client sends request to resource server, Resource server need to reach out authorization server(Spring oauth 2.0) for bearer token validation.
JWT tokens contains information about its expiry along other user information and self sufficient to work in stateless sessions, Here we don't need to validate oauth 2.0 JWT tokens from authorization server.
JSESSIONID Cookie is created by spring security by default, its not related to Bearer token authorization.

Comment: Yeah I actually understand the process when it is a jwt token, I used that one in the past. 
When you are not using jwt how does the resource server know who you are? 
Should I still see the header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx" but the xxxx will not be a jwt token?

Comment: @Funzo : If you are not using JWT, Then random access token(i.e xxxx) string doesn't contain user info, In this case validate token endpoint of authorization server(oauth 2.0 server) is used to validate token, After succesful validation this endoint will return the userId and user scopes which can be further utilized for controlling access of resource.

Answer (score 0):

Well the standard solution is an introspection request, as in step 14 of this post: https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/

Not all solutions are standards based though - and I always recommend capturing the HTTP traffic